# How to match list of patterns entered by the user in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Mozilla addon has a [MatchPattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) API which compares URL with a pattern. What I look for is not a fixed URL pattern but a list given by the user. The examples in the link provided by mozilla assume a hardcoded pattern. How can I make the variable `match` reads a list of URLs in the storage?

```
var match = new MatchPattern("*://mozilla.org/");

var uri = BrowserUtils.makeURI("https://mozilla.org/");
match.matches(uri); //        < true

uri = BrowserUtils.makeURI("https://mozilla.org/path");
match.matches(uri); //        < false
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please, at least, provide examples of what you desire.

Comment: FYI: If at all possible, you should be using [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) instead of the Add-on SDK. As of this point, only WebExtension based extensions are being accepted for review and listing on AMO (you can still provide updates to already listed extensions that are not based on WebExtensions). Support for non-WebExtensions based extensions will be removed from the release version of Firefox as of Firefox 57, scheduled for 2017-11-14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned to be so trivial. Simply, by having the reference URLs stored in an array, then, build a pattern, iterate over the array items one-by-one till you find a match of the url in hand with any of the array items.

I ended up using `search` funcion rather than `match`. The piece looks like this:

```
//the url to be tested.
var url="www.example.com";
for (var x=0; x<myArray.length; x++) //loop over the list
{
//for a constructing a RegEx in a string. 
//the following says the pattern startes with myArray[x], followed by "/[anything]/"
//We use "\\" in the string to represent "\" in the Regex. 
//We write "\\/" in the string to represent the Regex "\/"

var pattern= "("+myArray[x]+")"+"(\\/.*)*(\\/)*";"

//test if the pattern equals the value

if(url.search(pattern)==0)
 console.log("url matched");
else
console.log("url did not match");
}//end for
```